# disable dropdown options based on the previously selected dropdown values using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, disabled-input

I have three dropdowns with the same options. What i want is, when i selecte an option from a dropdown, the same option from the other two dropdowns to be disabled, except from the first one (the option 'Select One').

For this i am using the following logic, but here when one dropdown is selected to one value instead of disabling that selected value from the remaining two dropdowns, its disabling from the all of these three dropdowns this i don't want. The disabling of value should happen to the remaining ones but not for the current dropdown.

How can i do this?

```
<select class="form-control positionTypes">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control positionTypes">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control positionTypes">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("select.positionTypes").change(function () {
    $("select.positionTypes option[value='" + $(this).data('index') + "']").prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).data('index', this.value);
    $("select.positionTypes option[value='" + this.value + "']:not([value=''])").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/3pfo1d1f/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/3pfo1d1f/7/

```
$("select.positionTypes").change(function () {
    $("select.positionTypes option[value='" + $(this).data('index') + "']").prop('disabled', false); //reset others on change everytime
    $(this).data('index', this.value);
    $("select.positionTypes option[value='" + this.value + "']:not([value=''])").prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).find("option[value='" + this.value + "']:not([value=''])").prop('disabled', false); // Do not apply the logic to the current one
});
```

Comment: hi, I have somthing similar, but the *dropdowns are inside a table*, any chance you can show me how to do the same inside an HTML table that contains dropdowns in the 2nd col, I posted a question

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way of doing this. you can achieve the same with simple logic and its easily understandable even for a beginner as well.

**How it works:**

- Reset all the previous selection made on other `dropdowns`
- Disable the selected option on all `dropdowns` excluding current dropdown.

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$(function () {
    $(".positionTypes").on('change', function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        var otherDropdowns = $('.positionTypes').not(this);
        otherDropdowns.find('option').prop('disabled', false); //reset all previous selection
        otherDropdowns.find('option[value=' + selectedValue + ']').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/3pfo1d1f/10/)

Comment: hi @dreamweiver , I have somthing similar, but the *dropdowns are inside a table*, any chance you can show me how to do the same inside an HTML table that contains dropdowns in the 2nd col, I posted a question

Comment: hi, this works well, but how to disable values from `other dll selected options` on $this.selected DDL - the current one is not disabled in your code

Comment: How can we disable the other selections on the `current $this` as well?

Comment: @transformer: if you want to disable options for all the dropdown's including current one, then comment this line,`//var otherDropdowns = $('.positionTypes').not(this);`

Comment: Hi @dreamweiver  commenting out `//var otherDropdowns..` removes the definition and i get `Uncaught ReferenceError: otherDropdowns is not defined`.

Comment: How does the reset work, I just want all dropdown options to be disabled based on the selection. If a new option is selected, I want the otherDropDowns to updated to reflect that as well. *For e.g. in my case I am dynamically appending a new row that has another drop down. Your code works well on other dropDowns, but not the current one*

Comment: my mistake, instead of commenting that line, just remove the `.not(this)` operation. `var otherDropdowns = $('.positionTypes');`

Comment: no errors, but still some [items that are not disabled](https://ibb.co/ejvtbF) - if I click on the *last dropdown*, with a page preloaded with items

Comment: hmmm, i am not quite sure what is happening unless i see a live demonstration of your issue. so could you create a `jsfiddle` and dump relevant code in there to replicate your issue. i can give it a try

Comment: What if an option is selected already, by an if statement when the table loads.  THIS script only shows when 'on change' .. What if Option 2 is selected already? How can we start out the options with all other Option 2s being disabled?