# Disable dropdown selections based on other dropdown selections - even if selected = "selected"

Tags: jquery, html, dom, drop-down-menu

I am trying to disable options in dropdowns if they have been selected in other dropdowns with jquery. The following link almost answered my question:

[disable dropdown options based on the previously selected dropdown values using jquery or javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140990/disable-dropdown-options-based-on-the-previously-selected-dropdown-values-using#new-answer)

But... my selections are already selected (selected = "selected") so the jquery doesn't work as it requires the user to make a selection for the code to initiate.

Is there a way to do this when your options are already selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to "trigger" a change on each select on document ready ?

Just add this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.positionTypes").each(function(){
        $(this).trigger("change");
    });
});
```

See [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/vyavNB?editors=1010)

Comment: Absolute Hero, I have been tinkering with this for hours!

Comment: And yes, this answered my question. Thank-you.

Comment: any chance you could help with this inside a table...  - the challenge is the cascading drop down [posted a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43192928/6085193)